# Using .dll file in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on asp.net (web application). I have to use time picker control in my page. Hence i downloaded 'time picker.dll' file from some website. I need to integrate this 'dll' file into my project. can anyone pls guide me in the same?

Answer (score 1):

You would add it as a reference in the project.  Right click on VS and add reference and browse to it.

In your file include a using statement for the namespace of the DLL and then you should be able to instantiate a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `"time picker.dll"` into the `Bin` folder of your web-app and add `<%@Register %>` directive into your [web-page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx) to use that control.

Comment: This is normally wrong, because normally the `bin` folder is put as "ignored" in your VCS (SVN, GIT, ...). You normally copy it in the source file folder (or in a folder named ExternalDependancies, or something similar) and add a reference. The [<%Register %>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1(v=VS.80).aspx)  part is correct

Comment: And yes, I know it's what Microsoft suggests for example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az5kdaz0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dll package the typical ASP.NET server control, you have to add reference to the dll (VS Studio Project -> References -> Right-Click & Add Reference, Browse the dll file).

Next thing to do is to add the control on tool box by right clicking on the toolbox and selecting the control. Now you can drag the control on the ASP.NET Design surface. Alternatively, you can use the object browser to check the control name and use the [register directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).